# Is my partitioning scheme for a 1TB SSD valid?

Tags: partition, ssd, partition-table

Can you  confirm whether I have set up my partitions correctly on a 1 TB SSD for ubuntu(mate)?
[image: Partition Table]

Comment: I am missing the mount points, I understand that you want to have 800GiB for /home and 20GiB for /, isn't it?

Comment: 20 GiB for `/` is a bit on the stingy side; I would allocate more space -- maybe 40 GiB. If the 100 GiB unallocated space is intended as overprovisioning then I'd say that you can reduce it to 50; if it's intended for another OS then you should consider leaving some space unallocated for overprovisioning -- 50 GiB should be nice.

Comment: You missed /boot partition = 500 MB , / partition of root = 40 GB when you did it as Server too. Because you didnt create /usr partition and /var partition.

Comment: use gpt to have more than 4 primary parts; and to avoid lot of troubles in future ; partitionne the first 200 gb in any way you like ; and creat 800gb at the end (for your files); in the future you'll like to test other OSs ... you will be able to reparts the first 200gb without touching your data(800gb) ; and yes 200gb is enought for many linux/unix alongside systems; NOTE repartitionning causes lose of memory capacity ; with this plan you'll kep your 800gb away of this effect !

Comment: 1 question
What is the purpose of setting partition flags?
Many 'recipes' that I have been following such as 

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/gparted-partition-guide-for-linux-and-windows-users/797 >Part 4: Create a UEFI boot partition. + swap + root + home partitions.
don't even mention them.

Answer (score 0):

For disk management always try to maintain partition by LVM not standard way. It will be better for you to **resize your partition** any time without data lose. But production environment keep it minds maximum /var and /home mount point are used. So it will be better if you allocated maximum size on /var /and /home.